# Bootstrap Datatables and excate match

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have jquery bootstrap datatabales which is client side data rendering and data is being read from json, now I have filter on top of the view/table with combobox, now  tables  column no 1 with the values like below :

Value A,
Value AB,
Value C,
Value CC

and If I select "value A" in the filter combobox, I see Value A and Value AB as filtered result in view/table:
my Jquery code as below : which is triggered on on change of the combobox:

Expected output : if I select "Value A" in the combobobx filter, the view/table should only display filter/view result of Value A only not "Value AA" should be part of result.

Please assist.

```
$('#combobox1').on('change', function() {
        regExSearch = '^\\s' + this.value +'\\s*$';
             otable   //where otable is comprises of whole table data.
                    .column(1)
                    .search(regExSearch ,false,true)
                    .draw();

        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got my answer, here it goes:

```
$('#combobox1').on('change', function() {

             otable   //where otable is comprises of whole table data.
                    .column(1)
                    .search( unescape("^"+$(this).val()+"$"), true, false, true) // answer
                    .draw();

        } );
```

Thanks.